$(n⊗n⊗n)×(n⊗n⊗n)$ , and $( n⊗n) × (n⊗n⊗n⊗n)$ where ⊗ is decimal digits concatenation
let's take any number, let's say 27 for example
, we form the following products
where ⊗ is decimal digits concatenation
$(n⊗n⊗n)×(n⊗n⊗n)$  =  $272727 × 272727$ = $74380016529 $
$( n⊗n) ×  (n⊗n⊗n⊗n)$ = $2727 × 27272727$ = $74372726529$
then you compare these expressions by numbers on the left and on the right until the numbers become different the numbers in the numbers are the same on the right and on the left, but they differ in the center, for example
743 8001 6529
743 7272 6529
It can be seen that the first three digits are 743 and the last four are also 6529. we find the first non-matching digits and write out the number to the last non-matching one, that is, here it will be
8001 для 74380016529
7272 для 74372726529
You find  difference
8001 - 7272 = 729
it turns out that this is square 27. In the general case, this is n². Сan you show that this is true in the general case?

What does "then you compare these expressions by numbers on the left and on the right until the numbers become different, for example" mean?

the numbers in the numbers are the same on the right and on the left, but they differ in the center. 743 and 6529 matching numbers.   8001  and 7272 different ones

If $n$ has two digits your two multiplications are $(10^4+10^2+1)^2n^2$ and $(10^2+1)(10^6+10^4+10^2+1)n^2$ so your subtraction is $(10^8+2\cdot 10^6+3\cdot 10^4+2\cdot 10^2+1)n^2-(10^8+2\cdot 10^6+2\cdot 10^4+2\cdot 10^2+1)n^2=10^4n^2$.  If $n$ has more digits the exponents increase but the basic idea is the same.
For many problems involving concatenation it is useful to turn it into sums of powers of $10$ like this.
